# CollectionViewSource Binding not updating when removing or adding item

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm having trouble with my combobox updating when binding to a list. All other controls properly update when I make changes. I'm attempting to remove an item from the drop down list from a button.

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=statusList}" x:Key="statusList"/>
```

.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding ID}" Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" Checked="Filter_Checked" Unchecked="Filter_Checked" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Filter21Days, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"></CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>
<CompositeCollection>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Filter" Visibility="Collapsed" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <CheckBox x:Name="ViewAllFilter" Content="View All" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" Checked="Filter_Checked" Unchecked="Filter_Checked" IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <CheckBox x:Name="Filter21Days" Content="Last 21 Days" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" Checked="Filter_Checked" Unchecked="Filter_Checked" ></CheckBox>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <CheckBox x:Name="FilterBydate" Content="By Date" Foreground="White" Margin="10,0,0,0" Checked="Filter_Checked" Unchecked="Filter_Checked" Visibility="Collapsed"></CheckBox>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Separator Background="White" Width="110" Height="1"></Separator>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource statusList}}"/>

</CompositeCollection>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

.

```
ObservableCollection<Status> _statusList = new ObservableCollection<Status>();
public ObservableCollection<Status> statusList
    {
        get { return _statusList; }
        set { _statusList = value; }
    }
```

Comment: This code works for me. You tagged it "sql". Where's sql?

Comment: You're right. The way I was manipulating the statusList was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was with the way I was manipulating the statusList. I had statusList = another list, which didn't trigger the property changed. Worked around it with a for loop like below.

```
statusList.Clear();
for (int i = 0; i < statusWindow.statusList.Count; i++)
{
    statusList.Add(statusWindow.statusList[i]);
}
```